# Searching for intersections in two tuples of tuples in python

Tags: python, tuples

Having the following problem. I'm reading the data from stdin and save it in list that I convert to tuple the following way:

```
x = int(input())
f = []

for i in range(x):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    f.append([a,b])

def to_tuple(lst):
    return tuple(to_tuple(i) if isinstance(i, list) else i for i in lst)
```

After this I receive two tuples of tuples looking something like that:

```
f = ((0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2), (0, 3))
s = (((0,), (1, 2, 3)), ((0, 1), (2, 3)), ((0, 1, 2), (3,)))
```

What I'm trying to do is to find the number of intersections between all inner tuples of `f` and each tuple of `s`. In my case "intersection" should be considered as an "edges" between tuples (so in `f` we have all possible "edges" and checking if there will be an edge between inner tuples in particular tuple of `s`). So for the example it should print `[3,3,1]`.

Basically, I know how to do in the simple case of intersection - so one can just use `set()` and then apply `a.intersection(b)` But how should I proceed in my case?

Many thanks and sorry if the question was already asked before :=)

Comment: maybe loop over f tuple and convert each tuple inside to a set and do intersection on it with each set in s. then set to the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General answer for overall amount of edges:

```
def cnt_edges(a,b):
   edge_cnt = 0
   
   for i in range(len(a)):
       node1 = a[i][0]
       node2 = a[i][1]
       
       for j in range(len(b)):
           inner_node1 = b[j][0]
           inner_node2 = b[j][1]
           
           if (node1 in inner_node1 and node2 in inner_node2) or (node1 in inner_node2 and node2 in inner_node1):
               edge_cnt += 1
   return edge_cnt

a = ((0, 1),(0, 2), (0,3))
b = (((0),(1,2,3)), ((0,1),(2,3)), ((0,1,2),(3)))

cnt_edges(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this can be solve by different ways. but I believe this is the easiest.

```
out = set() # holds the output
for ff in f:  # loop through f tuple
   ff = set(ff)  # convert to set
   for ss1,ss2 in s:  # loop through s tuple
       # you can select which tuple to do the intersection on. 
       # here I am doing the intersection on both inner tuples in the s tuple.
       ss1 = set(ss1)  # convert to set
       ss2 = set(ss2)
       out.update(ff.intersection(ss1)) # intersection and add to out
       out.update(ff.intersection(ss2)) # intersection and add to out

#if you want your output to be in list format
out = list(out)
```

Comment: is it intended that the result of out will be just set of generators?

Comment: Can you please provide working example so I can choose this answer

Comment: I have modified it to get you the exact result.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can proceed

```
a = ((1,1),(1,2))
b = (((1,2),(3,1)),((3,2),(1,2)),((1,4),))
l=[]
for t in b:
    c=[i for i in a for j in t if i==j]
    l.append(c)
print(l)
```

Comment: it produces empty list for your example for some reason :(

Comment: I tried to edit it